# Passing a List to View from Controller in .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am just trying to pass a List and display it dynamically in a table in the View. I have a Homepage Model and Homepage controller and the variables are being set right, but I can't figure out how to pass it to the view.

My model looks like this:

```
 public class HomePageModel
 {
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "ExtNum")]
    public string ExtNum { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "PhoneDisplay")]
    public List<PhoneDisplay> PhoneDisplay { get; set; }
 }
```

and this is the controller:

```
 public ActionResult Homepage(HomePageModel HpModel)
    {
        ViewBag.Welcome = "Welcome: ";
        ViewBag.FirstName = HpModel.FirstName;   
        ViewBag.LastName = HpModel.LastName; 
        ViewBag.Extlbl = "Extension: ";
        ViewBag.Ext = HpModel.ExtNum;
        ViewBag.Todaylbl = "Today:";
        ViewBag.Today = DateTime.Now;
        DBOps ops = new DBOps();
        HpModel.PhoneDisplay = ops.getDisplayInfo(HpModel.ExtNum);
        return View(HpModel);
    }
```

PhoneDisplay is a list that contains a line index, a description string and a 4 digit number. Each user will have at least 1 item in this list and maximum 6. I was able to pass the other parameters and display them in the view but I can't find a way to pass the list and display that dynamically.

**EDIT**
I made it this far but still can't find the list items.

```
    @model AxlMVC.Models.HomePageModel
    <table>
    <caption style="font-weight:bold">Your Phone Information</caption>    
    <tr>
        <th>Line Index</th>
        <th>Display</th>
        <th>Extension Number</th>
    </tr>
    @{
    foreach (var item in Model.PhoneDisplay) //problems here
    {
     <tr>
        <td>
             @Html.Display(item.numplanindex)
        </td>
        <td>
             @Html.Display(item.display)
        </td>
        <td>
             @Html.Display(item.dnorpattern)
        </td>
     </tr>
    }
 }
    </table>
```

**EDIT**
I debugged the cshtml file and the items in the foreach loop are being passed just fine too, but the table is not showing on the page and neither are the items all I can see is the caption and the headers for each column

[image]

Comment: What you have looks fine although you should probably be passing the model and not just the list to the view... What is the problem you're having?

Comment: show the markup for the view...

Comment: I still do not have a complete markup I just created a table with headers, and I was trying to access PhoneDisplay List which I was not able. I am passing the entire model to the view now maybe that will fix my problem

Comment: When I pass the model I get an error, "Argument type 'AxlMVC.Models.HomePageModel' is not assignable to model type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AxmlMVC.Models.HomePateModel>"Sorry for the noob question this is my first MVC app

Comment: solved that error, it was stupid as I am trying things from autogenerated code. But still can't access the List items

Comment: Try and see if the list is actually being populated by setting a break point on the `HpModel.PhoneDisplay = ps.getDisplayInfo(HpModel.ExtNum)` or `return View(HpModel)`. Make sure that your data access layer is functioning correctly. Also, what does your `PhoneDisplay` model look like?

Comment: I just did I was able to fill in the blanks in the edit above, by using Display instead of DisplayFor. I debugged it until the last line in model "return View(HpModel)" everything is set perfectly right but items are not being displayed.

Comment: We would need to see the `ops.getDisplayInfo(HpModel.ExtNum);` method definition.

Comment: it's returning a List of PhoneDevice, which is only three string numplanindex,dnoprpattern,display that's all

Comment: What you are doing here is totally wrong. You should not pass your Model to your View using ViewBags. Also, you shouldn't pass the label texts using ViewBags either, that's what Data Annotations are for.

Comment: I am passing the model as suggested by the first comment. the rest of the stuff I know they shouldn't belong there but I'm doing it for now just to get it to work like I want and then I'll figure out how to deal with html and annotations. please check the edit I will include a screenshot of my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Html.Display` displays "data from the ViewData dictionary or from a model" as stated on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee310174%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). What it means is that it searches for the key in the `ViewData` dictionary with the value you pass in or a property in the `Model` with the specified name. E.g. `Display("test")` would search `ViewData` for the "test" key and the `Model` for the property named `test`. Since you are passing in property values that cannot work. Your options are:

- Output the value directly, `@item.numplanindex`. This will output a string representation of the value.
- Use `Display`, although this is not recommended. You could do `Display("PhoneDisplay[1].numplanindex")` to display `numplanindex` property of the second item in list.
- Use `DisplayFor`, like `DisplayFor(model => item.numplanindex)`. This is a strongly typed version of `Display`. It will either displays a string representation of the value or a template for the type, if you have one. You can also manage how the output is displayed via Data Annotations, e.g. `DisplayFormatAttribute`.
- Use `DisplayTextFor`, like `DisplayTextFor(model => item.numplanindex)`. This method outputs the string representation of the value.

Since you already have data annotations on the model, you could modify your view like this:
@model AxlMVC.Models.HomePageModel

```
<table>
  <caption class="tableCaption">Your Phone Information</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhoneDisplay[0].numplanindex)</th>
    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhoneDisplay[0].display)</th>
    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhoneDisplay[0].dnorpattern)</th>
  </tr>
  @{ 
  foreach (var item in Model.PhoneDisplay)
  {
    <tr>
      <td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => item.numplanindex)</td>
      <td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => item.display)</td>
      <td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => item.dnorpattern)</td>
    </tr>
  }
  }
</table>
```

The line `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhoneDisplay[0].numplanindex)` also works if `PhoneDisplay` contains no items. Only property metadata is collected, expression as such is not executed.

Comment: Finally thanks, can you give me an example of how to use the annotations in the cshtml file. I have them annotated already in the model. Do I need to use DisplayForModel ??

Comment: @user2247823 you already have the `@model AxlMVC.Models.HomePageModel` declared so it's just `@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FirstName)` which produces "First Name" taken from `[Display(Name="First Name")]`. And `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FirstName)` gives you the value of `HpModel.FirstName`.